How should I receive payments when there is difference in amount when the amount is converted in one currency to another
I am using QBD SDK in C#. I update the entries, pay bills, settle invoices in QBD via json files. Now, I have to receive payment for an invoice. Let say the invoice is of 740 USD so that would be around 1000 CAD but the bank conversion rates will always have the latest current exchange rate for QuickBooks. So, if the customer paid the invoice fully and sends me the 1000 CAD dollars but after the conversion of it from the latest exchange rate it becomes 739.10 USD instead of 740 USD. Then how will I pay the full bill in USD in QBD.
obj is the object of json that is paresed in a model.
IJournalEntryAdd JournalEntryAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendJournalEntryAddRq();

IORJournalLine JournalLineAdd1 = JournalEntryAddRq.ORJournalLineList.Append();
JournalLineAdd1.JournalDebitLine.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue(account.FullName);
JournalLineAdd1.JournalDebitLine.Amount.SetValue(Math.Abs(obj.amount));
JournalLineAdd1.JournalDebitLine.Memo.SetValue(obj.comment);

IORJournalLine JournalLineAdd3 = JournalEntryAddRq.ORJournalLineList.Append();
JournalLineAdd3.JournalCreditLine.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue(bank.FullName);
JournalLineAdd3.JournalCreditLine.Amount.SetValue(Math.Abs(obj.amount));
JournalLineAdd3.JournalCreditLine.Memo.SetValue(obj.comment);

